# String Swap Before and After Comma

Tags: sql-server, string, swap

I have the table below

```
AdviserName
-----------
Tearle, Michael Hearn
Hearn Tearle, Michael
Van Der Welden, Luke
Welden, Luke Van Der
Brennan, Sony G
G Brennan, Sony
Rhammasamysundaran, Vishnu Brahma Kuma 
Brahma Kuma Rhammasamysundaran, Vishnu
```

Basically I need to re-arrange so it become FirstName MiddleName LastName. For example Michael Hearn Tearle or Sony G Brennan or Luke Van Der Welden.

I used below syntax but somehow it doesn't like if the middle name is before the comma like Hearn Tearle, Michael.

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempX') Is Not Null)

Drop Table #tempX

create table #tempX (AdviserName varchar(max))

insert into #tempX (AdviserName)
values ('Tearle, Michael Hearn'),('Hearn Tearle, Michael'),('Van Der Welden, Luke'),('Welden, Luke Van Der'),('Brennan, Sony G'),('G Brennan, Sony'),('Rhammasamysundaran, Vishnu Brahma Kuma '), ('Brahma Kuma Rhammasamysundaran, Vishnu ')

--select * from #tempX


select substring(advisername, charindex(',', replace(advisername, ' ', '')) + 1, len(advisername))+' '+ left(advisername, charindex(',', advisername) -1) as AdviserName from #tempX
```

Below is the result.

```
AdviserName
--------------------------------------
 Michael Hearn Tearle
, Michael Hearn Tearle
n, Luke Van Der Welden
 Luke Van Der Welden
 Sony G Brennan
, Sony G Brennan
 Vishnu Brahma Kuma  Rhammasamysundaran
n, Vishnu  Brahma Kuma Rhammasamysundaran
```

How do you make a query to cater both middle name before comma and after comma?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempX') Is Not Null)

Drop Table #tempX

create table #tempX (AdviserName varchar(max))

insert into #tempX (AdviserName)
values ('Tearle, Michael Hearn'),('Hearn Tearle, Michael'),('Van Der Welden, Luke'),('Welden, Luke Van Der'),('Brennan, Sony G'),('G Brennan, Sony'),('Rhammasamysundaran, Vishnu Brahma Kuma '), ('Brahma Kuma Rhammasamysundaran, Vishnu ')


select
    AdviserName,
    replace(replace(
    SUBSTRING(AdviserName,charindex(',',AdviserName),len(AdviserName))
    +' '+
     SUBSTRING(AdviserName,1,charindex(',',AdviserName))    
     ,',',''),'  ',' ')
from #tempX
```

Comment: Thanks Jayasurya but I need the order to be FirstName MiddleName LastName like Michael Hearn Tearle or Luke Van Der Welden. What you do only deleting the comma.

Comment: @AdhityaSanusi, sorry about that, I've made a minor code change. check now

Comment: YES !!! it's working. AMAZING !!!. Thanks Jayasurya for your help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with d as
(select AdviserName, charindex(',',AdviserName) as comma from #tempX)
select
ltrim(rtrim(substring(advisername,comma+1,100)))+' '+ltrim(rtrim(left(advisername,comma-1)))
from d
```

Comment: WOWW IT'S WORKING. Could you please explain how your query works? especially with comma+1,100 and comma-1?

Comment: `comma` is just the index of the comma in the string.  I did it in a CTE because I hate writing the `charindex` bit twice so it probably looks more complicated than it is.  100 is simply because the `SUBSTRING` function needs a length - this number actually needs to be the size of the longest `AdviserName`